# mysql recursive query not showing all possible results

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

I am trying to follow Train Routes example as in the link below

https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/02/13/introduction-to-mysql-8-0-recursive-common-table-expression-part-2/

My table is as below

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE `routesy` (
  `id` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stationA` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stationB` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dist` int(3) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `routesy` (`id`, `stationA`, `stationB`, `dist`) VALUES
(1, 'DO0182', 'DO0064', 10),
(2, 'DO0064', 'DO0147', 70),
(3, 'DO0064', 'DO0049', 80),
(4, 'DO0064', 'DO0139', 90),
(5, 'DO0206', 'DO0147', 140),
(6, 'DO0072', 'DO0139', 150),
(7, 'DO0008', 'DO0049', 260),
(8, 'DO0208', 'DO0008', 280);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH RECURSIVE paths (cur_path, cur_dest, tot_distance) AS (     
          SELECT CAST(stationA AS CHAR(100)), CAST(stationA AS CHAR(100)), 0 
          FROM routesy
          WHERE stationA='DO0182'
          UNION     
          SELECT CONCAT(paths.cur_path, ' -> ', routesy.stationB), routesy.stationB, paths.tot_distance+routesy.dist        
          FROM paths, routesy        
          WHERE paths.cur_dest = routesy.stationA 
           AND  NOT FIND_IN_SET(routesy.stationB, REPLACE(paths.cur_path,' -> ',',') ) ) 
       SELECT cur_path,cur_dest,tot_distance FROM paths;
```

| cur_path | cur_dest | tot_distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DO0182 | DO0182 | 0 |
| DO0182 -> DO0064 | DO0064 | 10 |
| DO0182 -> DO0064 -> DO0147 | DO0147 | 80 |
| DO0182 -> DO0064 -> DO0049 | DO0049 | 90 |
| DO0182 -> DO0064 -> DO0139 | DO0139 | 100 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jKFzgDFew8QQdzixPKPSda/0)

I was hoping to see results below as well as these are valid paths. Why does the recursion stop at 3 levels?

```
DO0182 -> DO0064 -> DO0147 -> DO0206
DO0182 -> DO0064 -> DO0139 -> DO0072
DO0182 -> DO0064 -> DO0049 -> DO0008 -> DO0208
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to @vtan707 answer, the way to make routes bidirectection is add another `UNION` like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE paths (cur_path, cur_dest, tot_distance) AS (     
          SELECT CAST(stationA AS CHAR(100)), CAST(stationA AS CHAR(100)), 0 
          FROM routesy
          WHERE stationA='DO0182'
          UNION 
          SELECT CONCAT(paths.cur_path, ',', routesy.stationB), routesy.stationB, paths.tot_distance+routesy.dist        
          FROM paths JOIN routesy ON paths.cur_dest = routesy.stationA 
           AND  NOT FIND_IN_SET(routesy.stationB, paths.cur_path) 
          UNION 
          SELECT CONCAT(paths.cur_path, ',', routesy.stationA), routesy.stationA, paths.tot_distance+routesy.dist        
          FROM paths JOIN routesy ON paths.cur_dest = routesy.stationB 
           AND  NOT FIND_IN_SET(routesy.stationA, paths.cur_path)
     ) 
     SELECT REPLACE(cur_path,',',' -> '),cur_dest,tot_distance FROM paths;
```

So the second `UNION` is the same as your first with `stationA` and `stationB` transposed.

Replacing the sytnax once in the result set is probably easier too.

ref: [mysql-8.0 fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jKFzgDFew8QQdzixPKPSda/0)

MariaDB has [CYCLE RESTRICT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/#cycle-restrict) as of 10.5:

```
WITH RECURSIVE paths (start, cur_path, cur_dest, tot_distance) AS (     
          SELECT StationA, CAST(stationA AS CHAR(100)), CAST(stationA AS CHAR(100)), 0 
          FROM routesy
          WHERE stationA='DO0182'
          UNION     
          SELECT StationA, CONCAT(paths.cur_path, ' -> ', routesy.stationB), routesy.stationB, paths.tot_distance+routesy.dist        
          FROM paths JOIN routesy ON paths.cur_dest = routesy.stationA 
          UNION     
          SELECT StationB, CONCAT(paths.cur_path, ' -> ', routesy.stationA), routesy.stationA, paths.tot_distance+routesy.dist        
          FROM paths JOIN routesy ON paths.cur_dest = routesy.stationB 
)
CYCLE start, cur_dest RESTRICT
SELECT start, cur_path,cur_dest, tot_distance FROM paths;
```

ref [mariadb-10.5 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=7ba01fa0ab9909ad426f8df32dbaec94)

note: this has small loops in the end of journey which I haven't worked out (hence 17 rows instead of 9 in the result - see fiddle).

Comment: The above answer works but hangs for a bigger dataset. I could see that you had posted an answer with cycle restrict for MariaDb 10.5 before you edited it. Can you please re-post the answer? It has solved my problem

Comment: Ha, worked it out `CYCLE cur_dest RESTRICT` will ensure that once its found route to a destination it stops. A more extensive search is need to find the optimal. `start`, `cur_dest` probably isn't 100% for this.

Answer (score 2):

With your given data in the table:

```
INSERT INTO `routesy` (`id`, `stationA`, `stationB`, `dist`) VALUES
(1, 'DO0182', 'DO0064', 10),
(2, 'DO0064', 'DO0147', 70),
(3, 'DO0064', 'DO0049', 80),
(4, 'DO0064', 'DO0139', 90),
(5, 'DO0206', 'DO0147', 140),
(6, 'DO0072', 'DO0139', 150),
(7, 'DO0008', 'DO0049', 260),
(8, 'DO0208', 'DO0008', 280);
```

and the starting point in the query "stationA='DO0182' ", we are only able to trace 3 levels as the query results has indicated.

The path is one-directional, i.e. Station A -> Station B is the only direction that is considered in the path (not Station B -> Station A).

Hope this is helpful.